# Managing Dependencies with Spock and Geb

Tags: unit-testing, grails, functional-testing, spock, geb

I am trying to write a fixture for a web app, and am running into issues understanding how to mock certain aspects of the application.

Our project has heavy dependancies on Redis, RabbitMQ, an external account authentication server for both authentication and licensing, Spring Security, and a Websocket Framework called Atmosphere.

All of these components need to be present for the App to even function. How do you go about creating mocks for objects when all of these components need to be present and working without injecting a bunch of extra logic into the production code?

Comment: `Geb` and mocking shouldn't really mix. You mock things for unit/integration tests, but use `Geb` for functional tests for which your actual app runs (with all its dependencies).

Comment: So Geb is not intended to be used as part of a build process for deployment?

Comment: It is a good idea to run your functional tests on your built application before deploying and you can use Geb for this. This built application however should not have anything mocked - your Geb tests run against the real thing.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That drastically reduced the complexity of writing these tests.